# Bintray : Maven-Publish with Gradle Bintray Plugin doesn't upload maven-metadata.xml checksum file

Tags: java, gradle, bintray, maven-publish, maven-metadata

I'm trying to deploy my java project to Bintray. The version being built itself uploads fine but in the package main folder - there is no checksum file for maven-metadata.xml (maven-metadata.xml.md5, maven-metadata.xml.sh1 or any other). I cannot find any way to configure it.

I'm using Gradle 4.10 (cannot upgrade due to various reasons),
maven-publish plugin for Gradle 6.5.1 (latest), jfrog.bintray.gradle plugin 1.8.5 (latest).

The publications and Bintray uploads are quite simple :

```
publishing {
    publications {
        BinTrayPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            groupId = project.group
            artifactId = project.archivesBaseName
            version = project.version
        }
    }
}



bintray {
    user = System.getenv('...')
    key = System.getenv('...')
    publications = ['BinTrayPublication']
    publish = true
    override = true // TODO - remove this in production
    pkg {
        repo = bintrayPublishRepoName
        name = <repo name>
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        userOrg = <org>
        version {
            name = project.version
            desc = project.description
            released  = new Date()
        }

    }
}
```

I found a way to produce a checksum file for one of the files in the version being built, but not a way to produce a checksum file for the maven-metadata.xml file in the repo's package.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching the Bintray Gradle plugin for the simple maven command man deploy-file which does everything exactly like I needed - checksum files are created for both artifact and metadata files.